# How create characters emplacements in a HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

Hello,
I want to create a HTML form to create a pdf file.
My problem : I don't find how create the boxes for the characters emplacements (see the following screen shot of an exemple of a pdf file)
[image]

It's just | and _ or image or an existing html element ?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These *should* be regular form `input` elements (most propably of type `text`) as they're going to be filled by the user.

They won't look the same as in this image though by default (they'll look better), you'll need to style them accordingly.